# How to fix this dent/crack/chip at the edge of the door of laminated wardrobe?

Tags: repair, cabinets, crack, laminate, chip

I  accidentally caused a chip/crack in my student accommodations wardrobe which I would like to repair rather than paying my accommodation for the whole wardrobe.

I would like to fix it.

Can anyone   suggest how this can be repaired? (*painted/sprayed/self adhesive paper of similar color?*)

I have attached the picture of the damage.

[image: damage picture]

Added Photos

[image]

[image]

Comment: The  Close up photo is not very informative, the quality is not great so it does not tell us much. A better photo and another one farther back will help.  You do  not tell us what the material  the unit is made of.

Comment: I moved the pictures for original poster to the question.

Answer (score 0):

This will be difficult to hide because it's directly in front. Also getting an exact match on the paint may be hard too.

The repair should start by sanding the rough edges around the damage. Start with a 120 grit sandpaper and than change to 180 grit. Sand only the lip of the original finish. Start with light pressure until your sure the finish will not continue peeling off.

Once the edge is smooth it can be filled. There's many products for the patching. The most likely to endure for a long while is auto body filler (Bondo). Apply the filler and over fill slightly.

It should be ready in a few minutes. Wear a breathing mask for the next step. Using the 180 grit paper sand the filler in a circular motion, checking often that the repair is flush with the original finish. Use your fingers to check.

Wipe any dust off the surface. Apply a similar type paint and color. You will have to bring a chip from the dresser to the paint store so they can match the color.

Comment: Be mentally prepared for the dorm supervisor/landlord to notice the repair and _not_ accept it and charge you for their own repair/replacement. That's not to discourage you from attempting the repair yourself, but just to prepare you that it may not be acceptable.